# Google Cardboard Magnet Refresh Not Working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I need help with my google cardboard magnet. I created a ball game and I want it so that when you pull the magnet, the ball will jump. The first round, my magnet works fine, but when I restart the level (by falling down) the magnet doesn't work anymore. I used a script called MagnetSensor.cs (https://github.com/theqwertman/UnityCardboardTrigger/blob/develop/MagnetSensor.cs). Here's my Ball Control Script. If you can, please help me. Also try to help me format my code when pasting it inside of unity forums; I don't know how to. That's why my code is messy:

```
var rotationSpeed = 100;
var jumpHeight = 8;

var Hit01 : AudioClip;
var Hit02 : AudioClip;
var Hit03 : AudioClip;
var distToGround : float;

function Start () { distToGround = collider.bounds.extents.y; }

function Update () {
    var rotation : float = rotationSpeed;
    rotation = Time.deltaTime;
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.back rotation);
    MagnetSensor.OnMagnetPull += JumpOnMagnet;
}

function IsGrounded () : boolean {
    return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distToGround + 0.1);
}

function JumpOnMagnet () { rigidbody.velocity.y = jumpHeight; }

function OnCollisionEnter () {
    var theHit = Random.Range(0, 3);
    if (theHit == 0) { audio.clip = Hit01; }
    else if (theHit == 1) { audio.clip = Hit02; }
    else { audio.clip = Hit03; }
    audio.pitch = Random.Range (0.9,1.1);
    audio.Play();
}
```

Comment: Please read the tags you are using. [tag:unity] is not related to [tag:unity3d].

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Writing good, easily to understand questions is the key to getting good answers in return. You can put your code in code blocks by using four spaces to indent. More information on writing good questions can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Nor is JavaScript applicable for Unity's "JavaScript", it is actually UnityScript.

Comment: It would help to see the "restart" code given that it works before and doesn't work afterwards. What problem are you having pasting code into the unity forums? there is a handy sticky in the scripting subforum explaining the code tags...

Comment: Lefty, here's my script for the restart scene:               #pragma strict

var maxFallDistance = -10;
private var isRestarting = false;
var level : String;

var GameOverSound : AudioClip;

function Update ()
{
 if (transform.position.y <= maxFallDistance)
 {
  if (isRestarting == false)
  {
   RestartLevel();
  }
 }
}

function RestartLevel () {
 isRestarting = true;
 audio.pitch = 1;
 audio.clip = GameOverSound;
 audio.Play();
 yield WaitForSeconds (audio.clip.length);
 Application.LoadLevel(level);
}